# How to write a MySql insert trigger based on inserted data value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to wrote a trigger for table users. when new user added, if his Title is IT related, then create a record in IT contact list table.
So I wrote  below trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test1` INSERT ON `Users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF INSTR(Title,'IT') > 0
THEN
INSERT INTO IT_contact_list (name,title) value (username,Title);
END IF;
END;
```

It has error 'unknow column Title in the field list' But it did exist in table Users and IT_contact_list.So what's the issue?Thx.

Comment: Is this an exercise, or a production system?

Comment: Sometimes the obvious is just so hard to see.  Review your INSERT statement.

Comment: @Jon Armstrong
Thx.Type error,but still not working.

Comment: Your correction is not correct.  Review INSERT syntax.  See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: review your columns and your insert statement it should look like this                  
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed and tested in workbench. Try this:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists test1 //
CREATE TRIGGER `test1` AFTER INSERT ON `Users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF INSTR(new.Title,'IT') > 0
THEN
INSERT INTO IT_contact_list (name,title) value (new.username,new.Title);
END IF;
END//

insert into Users values('john','HardwareIT');
insert into Users values('bill','Hardware engineer');
select * From IT_contact_list;

--result set:
 john    HardwareIT
```